# Script not being executed while navigating, it works only if I refresh the page

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to insert a script on a gatsby project, but the script doesn't load, it loads only if I refresh the page, not while navigating.

The html.js file is same only that I inserted this line of code in the head section :

```
<script src={'../src/general/sendData'}/>
```

The script doesn't show any messages while navigating, only if I refresh the page:

```
window.onload = function(){
 console.log('worked');
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`onRouteUpdate`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/#onRouteUpdate) API (from Gatsby browser, `gatsby-browser.js`):

```
exports.onRouteUpdate = () => {
 console.log('worked');
}
```

It's a helper triggered in each route change so it should fit your specs.